# How to evaluate $\int\limits_0^\infty {\frac{{{e^{ - x - \frac{1}{x}}}}}{{1 + x}}dx}$ in form of special function?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

Is there anyway to evaluate the following integral in form of special function or maybe an infinite sum ?

$I =\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - x - \frac{1}{x}}}}}{{1 + x}}dx}$

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, by the change of varaiables $x=e^t$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - x - \frac{1}{x}} }}{{1 + x}}dx} & = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{1 + e^t }}e^t dt}  = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{e^{t/2} }}{2}dt} 
\\ &
 = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{e^{t/2} }}{2}dt}  + \int_{ - \infty }^0 {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{e^{t/2} }}{2}dt} 
\\ &
 = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{e^{t/2} }}{2}dt}  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - 2\cosh t} }}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{e^{ - t/2} }}{2}dt} 
\\ &
 = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 2\cosh t} dt}  = K_0 (2)=0.113893872\ldots,
\end{align*}
where $K_\nu(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9).

Comment: How can you go from $\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{e^{ - 2\cosh t}}}}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{{e^{t/2}}}}{2}dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{e^{ - 2\cosh t}}}}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{{e^{t/2}}}}{2}dt}  + \int_{ - \infty }^0 {\frac{{{e^{ - 2\cosh t}}}}{{\cosh (t/2)}}\frac{{{e^{t/2}}}}{2}dt}$. I guess you use some even/odd exploitation but cannot wrap my head around your ides ?

Comment: I make the change of integration variables form $t$ to $-s$ in the second integral and after making this change I just rename $s$ as $t$. The equality you quoted is just splitting the path of integration at $t=0$.