# How to rewrite $\int\limits_{x = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)}}{{1 + cx}}dx}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

How to rewrite this improper integral in term of any special function $\int\limits_{x = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)}}{{1 + cx}}dx}$ or at least written it as an infinite sum ?

This is a follow up post from the previous one
[How to evaluate $\int\limits_0^\infty {\frac{{{e^{ - x - \frac{1}{x}}}}}{{1 + x}}dx}$ in form of special function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973766/how-to-evaluate-int-limits-0-infty-frace-x-frac1x1-x)

That is $\int\limits_{x = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\exp \left( { - x - \frac{1}{x}} \right)}}{{1 + x}}}  = {K_0}\left( 2 \right)$

Where ${K_M}\left( x \right)$ denote the modified Bessel function of the second kind

I hope that I could generalized the old result !

Notice that $a,b,c$ are all positive number.

Comment: Would you be satisfied by an approximation, or your request is for exact functions?

Comment: Yeah I also think so, an approximation may be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $0<c<1$
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{ \infty } {\frac{{\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)}}{{1 + cx}}dx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n c^n \int\limits_{0}^{ \infty } x^n\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)\,dx$$
$$I=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n c^n a^{-\frac{n+1}{2} } b^{\frac{n+1}{2}} K_{-(n+1)}\left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}\right) \qquad \Re(b)>0\land \Re(a)>0$$ that you could make nicer.

Comment: Maybe you forgot an integral symbol in the rightmost side of the first equation. Furthermore where does the Bessel function come from? Do you mind adding some details? *Bonne année d'Italie!*

Comment: @Raffaele. Thanks for pointing ! I shall edit  *felice anno nuovo !*

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{1+cx}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-cx)^n$ requires $|x|<1/c$, this doesn't work.

Comment: @J.G.: I guess the sum should be viewed as an asymptotic series for large $a$; so you have to cut it off at some (if necessary optimal) point. In particular $$\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} (-1)^n c^n \int\limits_{0}^{ \infty } x^n\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)\,dx \leq I \leq \sum_{n=0}^{2N} (-1)^n c^n \int\limits_{0}^{ \infty } x^n\exp \left( { - ax - \frac{b}{x}} \right)\,dx$$ for some integer $N$.